# return constantly changing variable python

Tags: python, recursion, counter

I am trying to return a constantly changing variable in Python 3, the variable is in a while loop, counting to the specified number, changing its value to zero, and starting again.
(e.g 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, **0**, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, **0**...)
Here is my code:

```
global x
run = True
def count(l):
    x = 0
    global run
    while run:
        x += 1
        if x == l+1:
            x = 0
        print(x)
```

And when I run `count(5)` It *prints* the desired results, But 1: I'm trying to find a way to constantly run that loop in the background, and 2: the variable needs to be *returned*, not printed

```
GetCount()
```

and have it *return* the desired results.

I have tried adding this to the end of the function:

```
try:
    return x 
finally: 
    count(l)
```

But then it crashes with *Maximum recursion depth exceeded during comparison*

So my questions are, 1: Is there a way to have x be continually returned without reaching Maximum recursion depth?, and 2: If there is, is there also a way to have `count()` be running in the background, so I can get x's current value, and if so how?

Comment: Can you provide any details as to the root desire to return a constantly changing variable?  What is the variable keeping track of, and why do you need to do this constantly vs as needed?

Comment: Please describe your intention with this program because I suspect you need something else instead of "constantly returning values".

Comment: The goal of the program was for me to access it elseware and call count(), to find whatever the current value of x was. For example, if I wanted to append a number to the end of a user-id.

Comment: Is a database table with an auto-incrementing field out of the question?  I guess I should clarify my question with, what is the use case? You want to provide some uniqueness for userids? Why not use guids?

Comment: user-id's what just an example...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) can help:

```
import itertools as it

c = it.cycle(range(6))

for x in range(10):
    print(next(c))
```

prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
0
1
2
3
```

Just use `next(c)` to get the next number.

```
print(next(c))
```

now prints:

```
4
```

because we stopped at `3` before. You can set your ID value with:

```
my_id = next(c)
```

Comment: Thank you, you answered both my question's(I did not see the edit)

Comment: @HaiVu Thanks for the hint. Removed.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a *generator* and to *yield* each value:

```
def count(l):
    x = 0
    while True:
        yield x
        if x == l:
            x = -1
        x += 1


for i in count(5):
    print(i)
```

Comment: `for i in count(5)` will result in an infinite loop :-) The solution is correct, btw.

Comment: @HaiVu, yep, that's what the doctor ordered

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to make a generator functions

> It looks like a normal function except that it contains yield expressions for producing a series of values usable in a for-loop or that can be retrieved one at a time with the next() function.
>
> Usually refers to a generator function, but may refer to a generator iterator in some contexts. In cases where the intended meaning isn’t clear, using the full terms avoids ambiguity.

You make a generator in cases where you want a series of value to be calculate in a certain way but don´t need all of then at once because you only need one at a particular time and/or there are too many or even infinite of them.

A generator will remember were if was at the moment of yielding a value and will resume its calculation from that point on went a new value is required.

@Mike Muller already give you the perfect solution to your problem, so how about another example, like the Fibonacci number, there are infinite of them, but you can make a generator that give you all of them like this

```
def Fib():
    Fn  = 0
    Fn1 = 1
    while True:
        yield Fn
        Fn,Fn1 = Fn1, Fn+Fn1
```

this will give you every single Fibonacci number one at the time as you ask for them

```
>>> fibo=Fib()
>>> for i in range(10):
    print("the",i,"-th fibonacci number is:",next(fibo))


the 0 -th fibonacci number is: 0
the 1 -th fibonacci number is: 1
the 2 -th fibonacci number is: 1
the 3 -th fibonacci number is: 2
the 4 -th fibonacci number is: 3
the 5 -th fibonacci number is: 5
the 6 -th fibonacci number is: 8
the 7 -th fibonacci number is: 13
the 8 -th fibonacci number is: 21
the 9 -th fibonacci number is: 34
>>> next(fibo) #10-th
55
```